# Could electro-osmotic pumping be used to pump 90 ml water at 10 bars in about 25 seconds?

Tags: pumps

I am interested in pumping about 90 ml of water at 10 to 12 bars pressure in about 25 seconds.

Can this be done using electroosmotic pump? What is the energy consumption if it can be done..?

Regards

Comment: Sounds like a coffee machine... What do they use for pumps?

Comment: What is your research so far?

Comment: @ solar Mike... Coffee machines use rotary pumps that generate about 18 bar pressure I believe.. (Checked it on Amazon)

Comment: @mart....i am  beginning my research... No clue so far...

Comment: @devalvyas so add a pressure regulator.

Comment: @mike...its not about pressure regulation... I want to use electroosmotic  pumping. So wondering if it can be done or not..